# AJX and google SEO

Tags: html, ajax, seo

I've got the following simple page which uses ajax to load pages.

```
<head>
    <script>
    function loadPage(href)
    {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }   

    function setHTML(page)
    {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = loadPage(page);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setHTML('')">
    <div class="menu">  
      <table align="center">
      <tr><td><input type="image" src="img/welcome.png" onClick="setHTML('welcome.html')" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="image" src="img/ris.png" onClick="setHTML('ris.html')" /></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know if this way is good for google SEO? Will googlebot find and parse welcome.html and ris.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google now supports processing JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so this *should* not cause any problems.